# In Facebook, how to restrict my own posts in a group only visible to the group members?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups, facebook-privacy

In Facebook, how can I restrict my own posts in a group to only be visible to the group members? In other words, I don't like the posts that are only relevant to the members of that group being visible to my friends who are not in that group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your group name is "College Friends". Simply goto [Browse Groups By Membership](https://www.facebook.com/browsegroups/?category=membership) and select that group and post it there.

Another way is by creating a list. To do that just goto [here](https://www.facebook.com/bookmarks/lists) and click create a new list. You can suppose name it "Relevant People" and add the people in that "College Friends" Group. Then make a regular post and set the privacy to that newly created list "Relevant People". [image: Click "More Options".] [image: Select your newly created list "Relevant People".]

That way you can make a regular/personal status/post that will only be visible to people in "College Friends" Group.